# <script src="https://coinhive.com/lib/coinhive.min.js"></script> automatically appears in my website

Tags: javascript

This script automatically appears on the very first line of my site code. I tried everything to find how it is happened but couldn't. Anybody have any idea.
You can visit my site and see its source code: 
`www.bikaskhabar.com`

Comment: malware...must have come along with any free software that you downloaded..

Comment: There could be a ton of reasons here. If you check the source on the server, does it appear there? If so then someone has compromised your server somehow and you should look into reinstalling. If not then you'll have to check any dependencies you are using usch as CMS plugins or libraries to see if anyone of those could have done it. If you've recently made updates then try reverting those and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: look my site www.bikaskhabar.com
I tried looking all the plugins that i used in site but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

The Coin-Hive.com Miner Trojan is commonly bundled with other free programs or browser extensions that you download off of the Internet. You can remove it by installing Malwarebytes (use free trial version).

Comment: This isn't something on his local computer, you can clearly see that it is injected in the site source.

Comment: Then it is the webserver that is infected @Karl-JohanSjögren

Comment: Yes of course, thats why I commented on this. This answer was assuming that it was a problem with the clients browser.